# Rolling file appender based on size limit and backing up with a timestamp

Tags: c#, log4net

Is there a way I can set up log4net config such a way that if log file's size exceeds a certain limit existing log file should be renamed with a timestamp?

### Requirement:

E.g. When size exceeds 1MB, then my logs should look like

```
Log.txt
Log.12-07-2018.txt
Log.11-07-2018.txt
```

etc, where Log.txt is the current/latest log.

Note:

1. When rolling happens twice on the same day then log4net should append it to the file that already has the day's timestamp. For e.g. if roll on happens twice on *12-07-2018* and file size limit is *1MB* it would be OK to back up to *Log.12-07-2018.txt* file result in *2MB* file size.

### What I tried:

This is the log4net config I'm using:

```xml
<log4net>
  <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
    <file value="${LOCALAPPDATA}\foobar\Log.txt" />
    <encoding value="utf-8" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="1000" />
    <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />
    <datePattern value=".dd-MM-yyyy" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date %level [%thread] %type.%method - %message%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="All" />
    <!-- If the following line is not included the log file will not be created even if log4net is configured with this file. -->
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

### What I get:

```
Log.txt
Log.1.txt
Log.2.txt
```

---

**I want the renaming part to be based on timestamp and backup logic based on size**. When I try:

```xml
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <datePattern value=".dd-MM-yyyy" />
```

The naming of backup log file works, but then rolling happens based on date, not size.

Comment: Maybe change your 'rollingStyle' to Size again?

Comment: @DIe im not sure exactly how to go about it but changing it in the xml back doesnt work.

Comment: I think you'll also need the time in the file name, in case the file size causes it to roll twice on one day.

Comment: @stuartd good point, added a note in the question. For our app this will be a rare scenario.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [appending-date-to-filename-when-rolling-by-size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16858935/appending-date-to-filename-when-rolling-by-size)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be achieved, but not via configuration only.
A custom `RollingFileAppender` must be created and be referenced in the `Log4net` configuration as shown here below, where `PFX.RollingFileAppender` is loaded from assembly `PFX.Lib`.

The setting `staticLogFileName` ensures that the most recent file is always named `Log.txt` (as configured).
We (re)use the `datePattern` option to configure the date part in the log file name.
(For performance reasons, `countDirection` gets set to value 0 to reduce the number of rollovers; the most recent/last backup file will be the one with the highest number.)

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="PFX.CustomRollingFileAppender, PFX.Lib" >
        <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd" />
        <staticLogFileName value="true" />
        <countDirection value="0" />
        <file value="${LOCALAPPDATA}\foobar\Log.txt" />
        <encoding value="utf-8" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Size" />
        <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="1000" />
        <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />            
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date %level [%thread] %type.%method - %message%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="All" />    
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

The most challenging part in the requirements is the exclusing of the index/counter suffix in the file name; eg. Log-2018-07-16.**1**.txt
as Log4net internally tracks and uses this counter number to take care of eg. the backup file deletion.
Because of this, we'll have to manage the cleanup ourselves.

Log4net's implementation of the `RollingFileAppender` is not very open; there are very few methods to override
and there is no access to the current counter number tracking.
If you can't or don't want to include and modify the full source code of the original `RollingFileAppender` in your own project,
you can inherit from the original one in order to make as few as possible changes, as shown below.

If a rollup based on file size occurs we check whether todays log file (matching todays date; see requirement) already exists.
If so, no rollup occurs; only the content from `Log.txt` gets moved to todays log file.
If todays log file does not exist, an out-of-the-box rollover occurs. This creates a file with an index/counter suffix in its name; immediately afterwards this file gets renamed to match with the configured date pattern.
Because a new file got created, any depricated log files (more than the configured treshold) get deleted.

*(For brevity, the code below contains no exception handling.)*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using log4net.Appender;
using log4net.Util;

namespace PFX
{
    public class CustomRollingFileAppender : RollingFileAppender
    {
        private String _baseFileExtension;
        private String _baseFileNameWithoutExtension;        
        private String _fileDeletePattern;
        private String _folder;        
        private String _backupSearchPattern;

        public CustomRollingFileAppender()
        {}

        public override void ActivateOptions()
        {
            base.ActivateOptions();

            this._baseFileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(this.File);
            this._baseFileExtension = Path.GetExtension(this.File);
            this._folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(this.File);            
            this._fileDeletePattern = $"{this._baseFileNameWithoutExtension}*{this._baseFileExtension}";
            this._backupSearchPattern = $"{this._baseFileNameWithoutExtension}.*{this._baseFileExtension}";            
        }               

        protected override void AdjustFileBeforeAppend()
        {   
            if ((RollingMode.Size == this.RollingStyle) 
                && (this.File != null)
                && (((CountingQuietTextWriter)base.QuietWriter).Count >= this.MaxFileSize)
                )
            {                   
                DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                String todayFileSuffix = now.ToString(this.DatePattern, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                String todayFileName = $"{this._baseFileNameWithoutExtension}{todayFileSuffix}{this._baseFileExtension}";
                String todayFile = Path.Combine(this._folder, todayFileName);

                if (base.FileExists(todayFile))
                {                    
                    /* Todays logfile already exist; append content to todays file. */
                    base.CloseFile(); // Close current file in order to allow reading todays file.
                    this.moveContentToTodaysFile(todayFile);
                    // Delete and open todays file for a fresh start.
                    base.DeleteFile(this.File);
                    base.OpenFile(this.File, false);
                }
                else
                {
                    /* Do a roll-over. */

                    base.RollOverSize();

                    using (base.SecurityContext.Impersonate(this))
                    {   
                        this.deleteDepricatedBackupFiles();
                        this.renameBackupFiles(todayFile);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                base.AdjustFileBeforeAppend();
            }
        }

        // Moves the content from the current log file to todays file.
        private void moveContentToTodaysFile(String todayFile)
        {
            using (FileStream logFile = new FileStream(this.File, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(logFile))
            using (FileStream backupFile = new FileStream(todayFile, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(backupFile))
            {
                const Int32 BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
                Char[] buffer = new Char[BUFFER_SIZE];

                while (true)
                {
                    Int32 nrOfCharsRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
                    if (nrOfCharsRead <= 0) { break; }

                    writer.Write(buffer, 0, nrOfCharsRead);
                }
            }
        }

        // Rename backup files according to the configured date pattern, removing the counter/index suffix.
        private void renameBackupFiles(String todayFile)
        {
            IEnumerable<String> backupFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(this._folder, this._backupSearchPattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
            foreach (String backupFile in backupFiles)
            {   
                base.RollFile(backupFile, todayFile);
            }
        }

        // Keep the number of allowed backup files and delete all others.
        private void deleteDepricatedBackupFiles()
        {
            DirectoryInfo folder = new DirectoryInfo(this._folder);    

            IEnumerable<FileInfo> filesToDelete = 
                folder
                    .EnumerateFiles(this._fileDeletePattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                    .OrderByDescending(o => o.LastWriteTime)
                    .Skip(this.MaxSizeRollBackups + 1)
                    ;

            foreach (FileSystemInfo fileToDelete in filesToDelete)
            {
                base.DeleteFile(fileToDelete.FullName);
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I shouldn't post this as an answer (only difference is the staticlogfilename attribute and the file-datePattern values for the log extension) but I find it so ugly to post code in the comments...

```
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="path\Log"/>            
        <datePattern value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'" />         
        <appendToFile value="true"/>
        <staticLogFileName value="false" />
        <maximumFileSize value="1MB"/>          
        <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
    </appender>
```

This configuration of the .config file Works for me

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either. This nets: `Log.yyyy-MM-dd.txt
Log.yyyy-MM-dd.1.txt
Log.yyyy-MM-dd.2.txt` so on.